# I would like my python script to query the Confluence Cloud API and return all global spaces and their group permissions. I have had a go at script

Tags: python, confluence-rest-api

I have a requirement to extract all space data and group permissions for all global confluence spaces on my instance. I have written a Python script, from various sources on the internet but I cannot get it to work. I would really appreciate if someone could cast an eye over it and let me have any feedback on where I am going wrong.

I need the script to:
Pull in Space data for all global spaces
Pull in group permission data for each one
Print the results to a csv file
Here is my script so far:

```
import requests
import csv
import base64

# Confluence API credentials and domain
api_token = 'my api token'
email = 'my email'
domain = 'my domain'

# Basic Authentication
auth_string = f'{email}:{api_token}'
token = base64.b64encode(auth_string.encode()).decode('utf-8')
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Basic {token}',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}

# Get space data
def get_global_spaces():
    url = f'https://{domain}/wiki/api/v2/spaces?type=global'

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()['results']
    else:
        print(f"Failed to fetch spaces: {response.status_code}")
        return []
# Get permissions data for each space
def get_group_permissions(space_id):
    url = f'https://{domain}/wiki/api/v2/spaces/{space_id}/permissions'

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        permissions = response.json()['permissions']

        return [perm for perm in permissions if perm['principal']['type'] == 'group']
    else:
        print(f"Failed to fetch permissions for space ID {space_id}: {response.status_code}")
        return []

 # Write the results
def main():
    spaces = get_global_spaces()
    data = []

    for space in spaces:
        space_id = space['id']
        space_name = space['name']
        group_permissions = get_group_permissions(space_id)
        for perm in group_permissions:
            data.append([space_id, space_name, perm['operation']['key'], perm['operation'].    ['operation']])

    with open('confluence_spaces_group_permissions.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8')       as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(['Space ID', 'Space Name', 'Group Name', 'Permission'])
        writer.writerows(data)

    print("Data exported to confluence_spaces_group_permissions.csv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Run the script but it is failing when it is attempting to obtain the permissions for each space.